# GSM network network overhead issue

Tags: networking, installation, call, gsm, overhead

I am try to learn GSM network issues. I would like to know more about in detail "Trade-off between network overhead and call setup time". why network overhead will occurs and how it reflect on call setup time

Answer (score 0):

Seems an odd question (I am guessing it from some course etc?).

All networks will have an overhead to set up a call, so maybe this is referring to the extra work required to 'find' the terminating mobile device.

This requires a query to the GSM 'database' associated with the terminating subscriber, the HLR (Home Loctaion Register).

Call setup is generally prioritised over other traffic, including paging in the terminating cell to tell the terminating device there is a call - other than that there is not a lot of specific overhead. IN high congestion situations the terminating cell may not be able to page the device which can mean the call cannot be set up - maybe this is what the question was referring to.